# TinyMCE Javascript WYSIWYG editor not working with Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, rich-text-editor

I am trying to use TinyMCE with ember js. 
Code goes as follows -

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

And the textarea is inside the `text/x-handlebars` template as follows

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="course/discussion">
 <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>  
</script>
```

With the following setup, the TinyMCE is not working.

BUT, if I place the `<textarea>` outside the `text/x-handlebars` template, it seems to be working fine.

Any pointers on how do I make TinyMCE work when the `<textarea>` is inside the handlebars template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a view and use the `didInsertElement` hook to set up tinymce after the template is inserted into the DOM.

```
App.CourseDiscussionView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
  }
});
```

> http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

Comment: awesome, this works. But the bindings stopped working. Any tips on how do I make the bindings work  ?

Comment: Could you include the bindings in your example to be more specific?